# Getting total number of counts for distinct entrys for the same id

Tags: mysql, php

I have a table which is like this.

```
CREATE TABLE `ad_analytics` (
  `id` int(90) NOT NULL,
  `ad_id` int(90) NOT NULL,
  `advertiser_id` int(90) NOT NULL,
  `publisher_id` int(90) NOT NULL,
  `visitor_ip` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `type_ad` varchar(90) NOT NULL,
  `impression` int(90) NOT NULL,
  `view` int(90) NOT NULL,
  `clicks` int(90) NOT NULL,
  `date_event` date NOT NULL,
  `placed_date` date NOT NULL,
  `ending_date` date NOT NULL,
  `cpc` int(60) NOT NULL,
  `cpv` int(60) NOT NULL,
  `cpi` int(60) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I want to count the number of impressions, views, and clicks for a particular id for distinct IP Aka if there are four impressions from the same IP then it should be counted as one impression for a particular IP. How can I do that?

Sample data.

```
INSERT INTO `ad_analytics` (`id`, `ad_id`, `advertiser_id`, `publisher_id`,
    `visitor_ip`, `type_ad`, `impression`, `view`, `clicks`,
    `date_event`, `placed_date`, `ending_date`, `cpc`, `cpv`, `cpi`)
VALUES
(34, 49, 113, 109, '::1', 'Video', 1, 0, 0, '2018-04-16', '0000-00-00', '0000-00-00', 0, 0, 0),
(35, 49, 113, 109, '::1', 'Video', 1, 0, 0, '2018-04-16', '0000-00-00', '0000-00-00', 0, 0, 0),
(36, 49, 113, 109, '::1', 'Video', 0, 0, 1, '2018-04-16', '0000-00-00', '0000-00-00', 0, 0, 0),
(37, 49, 113, 109, '::1', 'Video', 1, 0, 0, '2018-04-16', '0000-00-00', '0000-00-00', 0, 0, 0),
(38, 50, 113, 109, '::1', 'Video', 0, 0, 1, '2018-04-16', '0000-00-00', '0000-00-00', 0, 0, 0),
(38, 49, 113, 109, '::1', 'Video', 0, 0, 1, '2018-04-16', '0000-00-00', '0000-00-00', 0, 0, 0);
```

I am expecting the result like this.

```
ad_id  Impression views click
49       1         0      1
50       0         0      1
```

Comment: IMHO you should add sample data and expected result, because it's unclear what you are asking.

Comment: The `(90)` means nothing on `INT`.  `INT` is a 4-byte signed number -2 billion to +2 billion, regardless of that number.

Comment: No `PRIMARY KEY`??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to `group by ad_id` and then `group by visitor_ip`
then select max for `impression`, `view` and `click`

so your query would look like

```
SELECT visitor_ip, ad_id,MAX(impression), MAX(view), MAX(clicks)
FROM ad_analytics
GROUP BY ad_id, visitor_ip;
```

**NOTE :** You should avoid using `reserved keywords` as column name.

Comment: if I want to show it to a particular user what can I do for example this query is showing error SELECT id, ad_id,MAX(impression), `MAX(view), MAX(clicks)
FROM ad_analytics
GROUP BY ad_id,visitor_ip
WHERE `publisher_id`= 49;`

Comment: Just add a `where` condition like `where ad_id = 1`

Comment: `SELECT id, ad_id,MAX(impression), MAX(view), MAX(clicks)
FROM ad_analytics
WHERE publisher_id =10
GROUP BY ad_id,visitor_ip;` This worked

Comment: please conside this question as well. https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/205429/count-total-number-of-impression-views-and-clicks-for-same-ad-id-for-diffrent-ip

Comment: @JitendraSoftgrid - Don't include `id` in the `SELECT`; it is non-deterministic.  Do in clude `visitor_ip`.

Comment: @RickJames Thanks for pointing that out, updated now.

Comment: @JitendraSoftgrid can you help me with the second question which is here.

Comment: @arunwebber You should ask a new question..

Comment: @JitendraSoftgrid This question is the continuation of the first one https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/205429/count-total-number-of-impression-views-and-clicks-for-same-ad-id-for-diffrent-ip As you have edited this answer i am just wondering whether you could be able to edit the second one as well.