# Count total number of impression views and clicks for same ad id for diffrent ip

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `ad_analytics` (
  `id` int(90) NOT NULL,
  `ad_id` int(90) NOT NULL,
  `advertiser_id` int(90) NOT NULL,
  `publisher_id` int(90) NOT NULL,
  `visitor_ip` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `type_ad` varchar(90) NOT NULL,
  `impression` int(90) NOT NULL,
  `view` int(90) NOT NULL,
  `clicks` int(90) NOT NULL,
  `date_event` date NOT NULL,
  `placed_date` date NOT NULL,
  `ending_date` date NOT NULL,
  `cpc` int(60) NOT NULL,
  `cpv` int(60) NOT NULL,
  `cpi` int(60) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I want to count the number of impressions, views, and clicks for a particular id for distinct IP Aka if there are four impressions from the same IP then it should be counted as one impression for a particular IP. Also if there is entry from two different ip for a same id then it should counted as 2?

Consider this data:

```
  INSERT INTO `ad_analytics` (`id`, `ad_id`, `advertiser_id`, `publisher_id`, `visitor_ip`, `type_ad`, `impression`, `view`, `clicks`, `date_event`, `placed_date`, `ending_date`, `cpc`, `cpv`, `cpi`) VALUES
    (1, 49, 113, 109, '::1', 'Video', 1, 0, 0, '2018-05-01', '2018-05-01', '2018-05-01', 0, 0, 0),
    (2, 49, 113, 109, '::1', 'Video', 0, 0, 1, '2018-05-01', '2018-05-01', '2018-05-01', 3, 0, 0),
    (3, 49, 113, 109, '::1', 'Video', 1, 0, 0, '2018-05-01', '2018-05-01', '2018-05-01', 0, 0, 0),
    (4, 49, 113, 109, '::1', 'Video', 0, 0, 1, '2018-05-01', '2018-05-01', '2018-05-01', 3, 0, 0),
    (5, 49, 113, 109, '::2', 'Video', 1, 0, 0, '2018-05-01', '2018-05-01', '2018-05-01', 0, 0, 0),
    (6, 49, 113, 109, '::2', 'Video', 0, 0, 1, '2018-05-01', '2018-05-01', '2018-05-01', 3, 0, 0),
    (7, 49, 113, 109, '::2', 'Video', 1, 0, 0, '2018-05-01', '2018-05-01', '2018-05-01', 0, 0, 0),
    (8, 49, 113, 109, '::2', 'Video', 0, 0, 1, '2018-05-01', '2018-05-01', '2018-05-01', 3, 0, 0),
    (7, 49, 113, 109, '::2', 'Video', 1, 0, 0, '2018-05-01', '2018-05-01', '2018-05-01', 0, 0, 0),
    (8, 49, 113, 109, '::2', 'Video', 0, 0, 1, '2018-05-01', '2018-05-01', '2018-05-01', 3, 0, 0);
```

For this this query giving me.

```
SELECT id, ad_id,MAX(impression), MAX(view), MAX(clicks)
FROM ad_analytics
GROUP BY ad_id, visitor_ip;
```

This answer:

```
(`id`, `ad_id`, `MAX(impression)`, `MAX(view)`, `MAX(clicks)`) VALUES
(1, 49, 1, 0, 1),
(5, 49, 1, 0, 1);
```

But i am expecting answer like this:

```
(`id`, `ad_id`, `MAX(impression)`, `MAX(view)`, `MAX(clicks)`) VALUES
(1, 49, 2, 0, 2),
```

Also in resultant row I need to consider publisher_id as well. How can I do that?

Comment: Replace `max` with `sum`

Comment: The result you are getting from that query is for two different `visitor_ip`. If you want a single result remove `visitor_ip` from `group by`.

Comment: @JitendraSoftgrid What i want is like this i want result from two diffrent ip impression has to be 2 if it is from two diffrent ip if the impression is from same ip then how many impression we are getting from  same ip should be always one

Comment: @JitendraSoftgrid I have edited the table data

Comment: `INT(90)` is the same as `INT(1)` -- you get a signed 32-bit number in either case.  Max value: +/- 2 billion.

Comment: What about AOL, where IP addresses are shared and move around?

Comment: It is "wrong" to include `id` in the `SELECT` because of the `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the expected result you want can be fetched using this query.

```
select
  ad_id,
  sum(impression) total_impression,
  sum(view) total_views,
  sum(clicks) total_clicks,
from
  (select
     ad_id,
     max(impression)  impression,
     max(view)  view,
     max(clicks)  clicks,
     visitor_ip,
     publisher_id
  from ad_analytics
  where publisher_id = 109
  group by ad_id, visitor_ip) t group by t.ad_id;
```

**UPDATE**

Removed columns from `select` that are neither in `group by` nor aggregated, and added `date_event`

```
select
  ad_id,
  sum(impression) total_impression,
  sum(view) total_views,
  sum(clicks) total_clicks,
  date_event
from
  (select
     ad_id,
     max(impression)  impression,
     max(view)  view,
     max(clicks)  clicks,
     visitor_ip,
     date_event
  from ad_analytics
  where publisher_id = 109
  group by ad_id, visitor_ip,date_event) t
group by t.ad_id,t.date_event;
```

Comment: I need to get this result for a particular publisher_id where can i add that?

Comment: This will result for a particular publisher_id?.

Comment: i want to show result for two distinct ad_id as well for example if there is an entry like  `(8, 49, 113, 109, '::2', 'Video', 0, 0, 1, '2018-05-01', '2018-05-01', '2018-05-01', 3, 0, 0);` This in the above it should also show click as 1 for the above ad id 50 but it is not returning that How can i do the same?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76831/discussion-between-jitendra-softgrid-and-arunwebber).